# Issue with JavaScript recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an object with nested objects. I need to get all the keys and values from all the sub objects into one array.

So I'm trying to do it with a recursive function, but I guess I'm doing something wrong...

The object :

```
var jsonobj = {

  "gender": "male",
  "country": "us",
  "phone": "06 12 34 56 78",
  "enterprise": {
    "parameters": {
      "company": "foo",
      "companyID": "12345678912345",
      "address": "adress principale",
     }
   },
  "contacts": [],
   "requirements": []
 }
```

Here is the function :

```
  function check(arr){
      var val = '';
      $.each(arr, function(k, v) {
          if (typeof v == "object" && v.length !== 0) {
              val = check(v); 
          }
      });

      return val;
 }
```

And this is the function using it :

```
function rec_res(obj_res) {
    var foo=[];
    $.each(jsonobj, function(k, v) {
        if (typeof v == "object" && v.length !== 0) {
            g = check(jsonobj); // calling the function
            foo.push(g);
        } else {
            foo.push(v);
        }
    });
    console.log(foo);
};
```

Expected output:

```
 [foo:{
  "gender": "male",
  "country": "us",
  "phone": "06 12 34 56 78",
  "company": "foo",
  "companyID": "12345678912345",
  "address": "adress principale",
 }]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/ump1bvh9/1/)

Comment: You didn't state what the problem is. Please add it to the question.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @zabusa I've updated the question

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks - check again - the function gives me error Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: `jsonobj` appears to be a global variable and you keep using that, when you probably meant `$.each(obj, ...)`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks - i'll check and keep you posted

Comment: How are you handling nested objects that have the same key? Aren't you then better off having an array of key values ?

Comment: @82Tuskers don't need - i know there won't be....

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i changed it - my bad.. the error is gone - but the function isn't iterate over the sub objects...

Answer (score 1):

You can create recursive function with `Object.keys()` and `reduce()` methods.

```js
var jsonobj = {
  "gender": "male",
  "country": "us",
  "phone": "06 12 34 56 78",
  "enterprise": {
    "parameters": {
      "company": "foo",
      "companyID": "12345678912345",
      "address": "adress principale",
    }
  },
  "contacts": [],
  "requirements": []
}

function rec_res(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, e) => {
    if(typeof obj[e] == 'object') Object.assign(r, rec_res(obj[e]))
    else r[e] = obj[e];
    return r;
  }, {})
}

console.log(rec_res(jsonobj))
```

Comment: Sorry - i can't implement it , need it to be native.... any idea why mine isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by native?

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonobj = {
  "gender": "male",
  "country": "us",
  "phone": "06 12 34 56 78",
  "enterprise": {
    "parameters": {
      "company": "foo",
      "companyID": "12345678912345",
      "address": "adress principale",
    }
  },
  "contacts": [],
  "requirements": []
}
var result=[];
function rec_res(obj_res) {
var foo=[];
  $.each(Object.keys(obj_res), function(k, v) {
    if (typeof obj_res[v] == "object") {

     var data = rec_res(obj_res[v]);
     if(data!=undefined && data.length!=0){
     data.map(function(d){
     result.push(d);
     });
     }
  }  else {
result.push({[v]:obj_res[v]});
foo.push({[v]:obj_res[v]});
  }
  return foo;
  });
//console.log(foo);
};
rec_res(jsonobj);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```